# SparkR mean : why must I use head(select(df, mean(df$age))

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, mean, sparkr

I found in documentation that I should do : `mean(df$c)` to calculate a mean and it doesn't work (it returns `Column avg(age)`, not the value)

I found on databricks, I should do :

```
meanAge=head(select(df, mean(df$age))
```

And it works !! But I don't know why/how

Especially, the head instruction is intend to return the first values of a data frame, not a single value. No ?

And is it the best way to calculate a mean ?

PS : `typeof(df)` returns 'S4'

Answer (score 1):

SparkR is a DSL (domain specific language) for manipulating Spark objects. `SparkDataFrame` is not `data.frame` compatible and operations on columns have different semantics.

`mean(df$c)` is just a description and it is not even bound to the data. It has to be placed in a context, here `select(df, ...)` and evaluated with action, here `head`.

If you find `head` confusing you `collect`:

```
 df <- createDataFrame(iris)

> df %>% select(mean(df$Petal_Length)) %>% collect()
  avg(Petal_Length)
1             3.758
```

or use `as.data.frame`

```
> df %>% select(mean(df$Petal_Length)) %>% as.data.frame()
  avg(Petal_Length)
1             3.758
```

In all cases you enforce execution and fetch the result as a `data.frame`. The difference compared to head is that it doesn't limit number of rows (not applicable for large datasets).